# Add x,y axis in d3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm really struggling to add x and y axis to my bar chart.
I find always different ways to add them and till now I haven't been able to make those ways work on my code.

```
 var maxVal = d3.max(d3.values(dataArray));                     

 var scale = d3.scaleLinear()                                   
     .domain([0, maxVal])                                       
     .range([0, 400]);                                          

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()                                    
     .scale(scale);                                             

 d3.select("#accordionChart")                                   
      .selectAll("div")                                         
      .data(dataArray)                                          
        .enter()                                                
        .append("div")                                          
        .style("width", function(d) { return scale(d) + 'px' }) 
        .text(function(d) { return d; })
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you're missing calls, something like:

```
// draws the x and y axes
svg.select('.xaxis')
  .call(xAxis);
svg.select('.yaxis')
  .call(yAxis);
```

Additionally, I didn't see code in your snippet for placing either axis, something like:

```
// append skeleton of axes to svg
svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'xaxis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')');

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'yaxis');
```

Comment: You can combine them in just one block: `svg.append('g').attr('class', 'xaxis').attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')').call(xAxis);`. And another way is doing `var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(scale)(svg.append('g').attr('class', 'xaxis').attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')'))`.

Comment: Should i first define the element g? Or is it automatically defined?

Comment: The element `g` is a group of [elements in an `svg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g). In my example, I assumed that a variable called `svg` had been defined. Based on your code snippet, you may have something like: `d3.select("#accordionChart").append('g').attr('class', 'xaxis')` (or with Gerardo Furtado's example). They key points are to: 1) append a container for the axis to your graph and 2) select the container and use `call` to draw it.

Comment: I would also recommend checking out [this example from Mike Bostock (the creator of d3)](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304). He adds a `g` element to his graph for the x and y axes, and then uses `call` to draw them to screen once everything's configured. He defined a variable `g`, but in the HTML you'd see `<g>`...`</g>`.